# KeyError When JSON Parsing

Tags: python, json

I tried to access 'gold_spent` key in some dictionary made from JSON file.

Here is my code:

```
import json
import requests

response = requests.get("https://sky.shiiyu.moe/api/v2/profile/tProfile")
json_data = json.loads(response.text)
print(json_data['gold_spent'])
```

When I run this I get this "KeyError: 'gold_spent'"
I don't know what I am doing wrong, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The data you are looking for is nested. See below.

```
print(json_data['profiles']['590cedda63e145ea98d44015649aba30']['data']['misc']['auctions_buy']['gold_spent'])
```

output

```
46294255
```

Answer (score 1):

You experienced an exception because `gold_spent` isn't at all a key of first level, you need to investigate the structure to find it. Accessing non-existing key in the dictionary would always end with [KeyError](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#KeyError) exception.

```
import json
import requests

response = requests.get("https://sky.shiiyu.moe/api/v2/profile/tProfile")
json_data = json.loads(response.text)

print(json_data.keys())
# dict_keys(['profiles'])

print(json_data['profiles'].keys())
# dict_keys(['590cedda63e145ea98d44015649aba30'])

print(json_data['profiles']['590cedda63e145ea98d44015649aba30'].keys())
# dict_keys(['profile_id', 'cute_name', 'current', 'last_save', 'raw', 'items', 'data'])

print(json_data['profiles']['590cedda63e145ea98d44015649aba30']['data']['misc']['auctions_buy']['gold_spent'])
# 46294255
```